# How to resolve smtp client host rejected access denied issues

Tags: asp.net, .net, email, smtp, asp.net-mvc-5

i am able to send email using gmail, but now i want send email using my domain

Following is the code which is used to send email using my domain

but facing access denied issue

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
client.Host = "mail.xyz.com";
client.Port = 25;
client.EnableSsl = true;
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("xxxx@xxxx.org", "xxxx");
                client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
MailMessage maili = new MailMessage();
maili.Body = password;
maili.Subject = "Password Reset Confirmation";
maili.IsBodyHtml = true;
maili.From = new MailAddress("xxxx@xxxx.org");
maili.To.Add(email);
try
{
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate(object s, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) 
    { 
        return true;         
    };
    client.Send(maili);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you enable "Server needs authentication" in your email client?

Comment: I think you need to contact your Hosting provider.

Comment: You need to contact your hosting provider. Each of hosting providers have their own policy